# python - Getting key with second and third maximum value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a JSON file something like this.

```
{
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities": 
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d": 
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities": 
 {
  "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
 }
}
}
```

Now to get the max visited city by a user or the key `b0:47:bf:af:c1:42` for each key I am currently parsing it into a dict and then using this.

```
for mac in dic_data:
    cities = dic_data[mac]['cities']
    most_visited_city = max(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])
```

But how to get second max visited city, third max visited city and so on. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `max`, you can use `sorted`.

That way you will get a sorted list based on `count`:

```
d = {
"b0:47:bf:af:c1:42":
 {
 "No. of visits": 10, "cities":
    {
      "Mumbai": {"count": 5,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Kolkata": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
      "Amritsar":{"count": 3,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
     }
},
"c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d":
 {
 "No. of visits": 24, "cities":
 {
  "Mumbai": {"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Kolkata": {"count": 20,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"},
  "Amritsar":{"count": 2,"last_visited": "5/22/2016"}
 }
}
}

for mac in d:
    cities = d[mac]['cities']

    sorted_cities = sorted(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])
    # or if you want the sort to be the other way around
    reversed_sorted_cities = sorted(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'],
                                    reverse=True)
    print sorted_cities


>> ['Kolkata', 'Amritsar', 'Mumbai']
   ['Amritsar', 'Mumbai', 'Kolkata']
```

**UPDATE** To get the output you asked in the comments:

```
d = { ... }

info = {}

for mac in d:
    cities = d[mac]['cities']

    info[mac] = sorted(cities, key=lambda x: cities[x]['count'])

print info

>> {'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42': ['Kolkata', 'Amritsar', 'Mumbai'],  
    'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d': ['Mumbai', 'Amritsar', 'Kolkata']}
```

Can also be done in one line using dictionary comprehension:

```
info = {mac: sorted(d[mac]['cities'], key=lambda x: d[mac]['cities'][x]['count']) 
        for mac in d}
```

Comment: this definitely helps thanks. I just had one more doubt. if I want to get max visited city second max visited(or sorted list) by any user rather than each user. So, for this case output will be like `['c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d' : 'Kolkata' , 'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42' : 'Mumbai', 'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42' : 'Amritsar']` and so on

Comment: Sorry, I think i couldn't explain my question properly. This is again you have done is for each mac. What I want is to sort on `"count"` for whole dictionary and return the output both Key and Subkey as count is a subkey of subkey of key. Just have a look on output. `['c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d' : 'Kolkata' , 'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42' : 'Mumbai', 'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42' : 'Amritsar', 'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d' : 'Mumbai' , 'c0:ee:fb:71:be:0d' : 'Amritsar', 'b0:47:bf:af:c1:42' : 'Kolkata']` .

Comment: The values of `"count"` corresponding to this key sub key pair is `[20,5,3,2,2,2]`